# Does git pull operate on the current branch?

Tags: git

Is it correct that `git pull` operates on branches?

In a repository, when running `git pull` on different branches, will it do different things?

When not specifying any argument after `git pull`,

- does it only pull to the current branch from a same-name branch in the remote `origin`?
- does it do anything for any other branch?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it would mess with other branches. And I don't think it merges from same-name branches but from the branch that is being "tracked" by the current branch (which doesn't necessarily have the same name).

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: `pull` performs a `fetch` then does a `merge`. It will only change your current *local* branch in the `merge` part, but the `fetch` part will update all of the other remote branches if they had changes since the last fetch.

Comment: @crashmstr: the `git fetch` that `git pull` performs is a *restricted* fetch, so it only updates one remote-tracking branch. I think some people like this as it avoids downloading objects for branches you're not using. In the repositories I use, there's no need to avoid downloading such objects, but some might use Git in a way such that there is.

Comment: Both of the above two answers are good. The second answer by Adrianoplis, the short one, is the "right" answer to the intended question. The first answer by torek, the very long one, is "correct and complete" but also illustrates why some very smart people are scared of git and why there is still need for a good tutorial that explains the simple things one wants to do with git simply and provides a simple set of use case transition diagrams.

Answer (score 8):

First, **don't use `git pull`**.  This command is *never* needed, and you will be better off if you avoid it until you are a Git-master.  But if you insist on using it, because it's convenient—and it *is* convenient—remember that it just runs `git fetch` first, and then, depending on various things, usually runs `git merge` second.

> Is it correct that `git pull` operates on branches?

Yes—but it's better to think of `git pull` as running *two* Git commands, because that's what `git pull` *does*.

> In a repository, when running `git pull` on different branches, will it do different things?

It's not clear what you mean by "on different branches" and "do different things".  You might mean:

```
git checkout branch1; git pull; git checkout branch2; git pull
```

or:

```
git checkout branch1; git pull origin branch2 branch3
```

and the latter is *very* different.  (The short answer to "when to use this form" is *never*.  The long answer is "Not yet: first learn about octopus merges, then re-read the documentation.  Then, once you are a Git master, you will realize that you probably should never do an octopus merge directly with `git pull` anyway, but at least now you know when it's safe to use `git pull` at all.")

The former—running `git pull` while on `branch1`, then running `git pull` again while on `branch2`—just goes through the four steps listed below twice, once on `branch1`, and then again on `branch2`.

> When not specifying any argument after `git pull`,
>
> - does it only pull to the current branch from a same-name branch in the remote `origin`?
> - does it do anything for any other branch?

Let's dispose of the second part first, because that's easy: "no, as long as you are not talking about *remote-tracking branches*."

Next, we need to note an assumption: that the remote is named `origin`.  You can have more than one remote, and if you do, obviously *at most one of them* is named `origin`.  Even if you have only one remote, you can call it whatever you want.  So the idea that the remote is `origin` is a bit shaky to start with.

(Usually, though, it *is* `origin`.  Most people have just one remote, and it's named `origin`, so there's only *the* remote, not "one of seven different remotes to pick from" or whatever.)

When you run `git pull` with no arguments, Git will:

1. Identify the current branch's *upstream*.  For instance, the upstream of `branch1` is probably `origin/branch1`.  Note that there are two parts to this upstream:

   - The name of the remote, such as `origin`.
   - The name of a branch *found on the remote*, such as `branch1`.

   To make a *remote-tracking branch*, Git effectively pastes these two parts together, which is why we see it as `origin/branch1`.  But there are still the two parts.

   There is no requirement that the upstream branch name *match* the local branch name.  It's just a *good idea*.

   (There are times when you must violate this "good idea", when you have two or more remotes.  Suppose, for instance, that remote `fred` has a branch named `develop` and different remote `susan` has a branch named `develop`.  You now have both `fred/develop` and `susan/develop` in *your* repository.  You want to do something with both of those; what branch names will you use?  Maybe you can call one `fred-develop` and the other `susan-develop`.  But now the upstream name doesn't match the local name any more: the upstream for `fred-develop` is `fred/develop`, not `fred/fred-develop`.)
2. Split up this upstream into its two parts: remote, and name-of-branch *as seen on the remote*.
3. Run `git fetch` with several arguments.  The `git fetch` step will call up another Git using the URL for the remote.  Once your Git has the foreign Git on the Internet-phone, your Git will obtain any new commits they have on *their* branch, that you do not have anywhere yet.

   Let's say the current branch is `branch1` and the upstream is `origin/branch1`.  If your own Git is not too ancient (is at least version 1.8.4), this updates your `origin/branch1`.  (If your Git is older than that, the arguments that `git pull` provides prevent your remote-tracking branch from being updated.  This is not such a good situation, and you should update your Git version.  It all *works*, it's just hard to explain.  If you avoid `git pull` entirely, the weird way that Git 1.8.3 and earlier does this no longer matters, because `git fetch origin` updates *all* your remote-tracking branches, even in these ancient versions of Git.)

   Now that `git fetch` has those new commits in *your* repository, under your `origin/branch1` *remote-tracking branch*, you're all set.  A later `git fetch` will finish very quickly, because you now *have* those new commits.
4. Run `git merge`, *or some other Git command*, with several arguments.

It's this last step—usually `git merge`—that affects *your* branch.  When `git merge` succeeds, it often *makes a new commit*.  As with all normal Git commands, making a *new* commit *adds the commit to your current branch.*  When `git merge` does a fast-forward instead of making a new commit, that *also* affects your current branch.

Hence, we can say this: *When `git pull` runs `git merge`, the `git merge` step affects your current branch in the same way that `git merge` **always** affects your current branch.*

You can ask `git pull` to run a *different* second command, though.  Specifically, you can set things up so that `git pull` runs `git rebase` instead of `git merge`.  To figure out what that does, we must look at what `git rebase` does, and that's more complicated—but in the end, it also affects your current branch, just like `git merge`.<sup>1</sup>  Hence we can also say: *When `git pull` runs `git rebase`, the `git rebase` step affects your current branch in the same way that `git rebase` **always**<sup>1</sup> affects your current branch.*

#### Putting this all together

When we put all these facts together, we end up seeing that `git pull`'s *second* command is what affects the current branch.  And, it *only* affects the current branch, because `git merge` and `git rebase` work *only* on the current branch.

(The *first* command—the `git fetch` step—affects *remote-tracking branches*.  But since those are just your Git's way of remembering what it got from a foreign Git, the last time it got things from that foreign Git, that's not very important.)

Last, **don't use `git pull`**.  Use `git fetch`, followed by whichever command you choose based on what came in with the `fetch`: `git merge` or `git rebase`.

---

<sup>1</sup>There is a way to make `git rebase` affect a different branch, but—fortunately—`git pull` doesn't use it.  (You probably shouldn't either, unless you know what you are doing.  It is pretty trivial: it literally just does a `git checkout` of another branch-name first, then proceeds as if you had done this yourself, and had not specified the extra branch-name.)

Answer (score 6):

If you do a git pull from your branch it will only pull new changes committed to that branch. So for example if I was also making changes to your branch and pushed new changes to the repo. You could do a git pull from your branch and it would update with my changes.