# What happens if I try to rebase a commit that is already pushed to a development branch

Tags: git, github, rebasing

The use case is following

I pull from the development branch then
I make some code changes and push then

After few days I come back and do to a git status, this shows that I am ahead of the master branch by 1 commit, obviously I haven't pulled from the master for a couple of days

Now before I make my changes I decide to do a git pull with rebase , git pull --rebase origin master

The question is: will the commit that I had in my local repo branch go on top of the master or since I had already pushed it I will simply get to the tip of the global master/remote branch?

I am new to concept of rebasing so please help explain this.

Comment: Currently on doing a git status I see that the previous commit that was already pushed is still on the HEAD, even though it was pushed couple of days back and others have made changes, in this case what command should I use?

Comment: rebase will make your local commits stay on top, so if you don't have pushed commits yet, rebase will do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the following.

```
          D---E---F origin/master
         /
A---B---C---X master
        ^
        origin/master in your repository
```

A few days ago your local master and origin/master were both in sync and each had commits `A`, `B` and `C`. At some point you committed `X` in your local master. And concurrently others pushed commits `D`, `E` and `F` to origin/master.

At this point if you run `git pull --rebase origin master`, will pull all commits from the origin/master as is and the commit `X` will be replayed over top of `F` and a new commit id will be generated `X'`.

The new commit graph will look like:

```
                     origin/master
                    /
A---B---C---D---E---F---X' master
                    ^
                    origin/master in your repository
```

So yes, the old commit `X` will be rebased at the top of your local master as commit `X'`.

**EDIT:**

> the question in this use case what if I had pushed X and then D,E,F were made, how will my local branch look asfter i execute the pull with rebase now?

In this case, after pushing your commit X, both your local repository and origin/master will be in sync.

```
             origin/master
            /
A---B---C---X master
            ^
            origin/master in your repository
```

After few days the commits `D`, `E` and `F` are pushed by others to the origin/master. The commit graph will then look like this:

```
             D---E---F origin/master
            /
A---B---C---X master
            ^
            origin/master in your repository
```

Now if you run `git pull --rebase origin master` it will give identical results to the `git pull origin master` command, because there is nothing to rebase from. You do not have have any commits ahead of origin/master. At the end of this command your graph will look like this:

```
                          origin/master
                         /
A---B---C---X---D---E---F master
                        ^
                        origin/master in your repository
```

Since your commit `X` was already in origin/master, it will not be replayed on top of `D`, `E` and `F`.

Comment: the question in this use case what if I had pushed X and then D,E,F were made, how will my local branch look asfter i execute the pull with rebase now?

Comment: could you please check this "Since your commit X was already in origin/master, it will not be replayed on top of D, E and F", but what I see after git log is that X is still at top, what I did was i pushed X, then for couple of days did nothing, then when I did a git status, i got that i am ahead by 1 commit, then I did git pull --rebase origin master then did a git log and se that X is on top.

Comment: If you pushed X and your push was successful, then it would be the scenario I described. If you did not push or pushed but the push was not successful, then it explains the behavior you see. There are reasons why pushing a commit could be unsuccessful

Comment: The push was successful I have the push ID/gerit ID of the push

Answer (score 0):

> The question is: will the commit that I had in my local repo branch go on top of the master or since I had already pushed it I will simply get to the tip of the global master/remote branch?

If by "global" you mean "remote", then yes, your local branch is going to be rebased on top of `origin/master`. See below for a longer explanation.

---

Based on your question, your repository started out looking like this:

```
o---o--------------o
    ^              ^   
    master         development
    origin/master  origin/development
```

Your local `master` branch was in sync with the remote `origin/master` branch; also, you had a local `development` branch with 1 commit, which you pushed to the remote repository thus creating `origin/development`.

Now, assuming your current branch is `development`, if you run

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Git is going to fetch any new objects from the `origin` remote and update your remote tracking branch `origin/master`:

```
                  origin/master
                  ⌄
          o---o---o
         /
    o---o--------------o
        ^              ^   
        master         development
                       origin/development
```

Then, it's going to *rebase* your current branch (in this case `development`) on top of the updated `origin/master` branch:

```
                  origin/master  development
                  ⌄              ⌄
          o---o---o--------------o'
         /         
    o---o--------------o
        ^              ^   
        master         origin/development
```

Note that your local `master` branch is still pointing to the same commit it did before—that's because the second part of `git pull` (merge or rebase) always operates on the *current branch*, in your case `development`.

Now, if you were to push your local `development` branch after the pull operation is complete, you would update the `origin/development` remote tracking branch to point to the rebase commit:

```
                                 origin/development
                  origin/master  development
                  ⌄              ⌄
          o---o---o--------------o'
         /         
    o---o
        ^                 
        master
```

Again, your local `master` is unchanged until you do:

```
git checkout master && git merge origin/master
```

The `git pull` command is a complex beast, since it does wildly different things based on which branch you're on when you invoke it and which arguments you pass to it.

Here's what the documentation has to say about [the form with three arguments](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_examples):

> Merge into the current branch the remote branch next:
>
> ```
> $ git pull origin next
> ```
>
> This leaves a copy of next temporarily in `FETCH_HEAD`, and updates the remote-tracking branch `origin/next`.

I also suggest reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43555688/26396) for a more detailed explanation of how `git pull` behaves in different scenarios.